# Pass Arguments for Callback in Event Listener

Tags: javascript, arguments, addeventlistener

when i try to pass arguments in addEventListener it behaves unusual

```
var animateFunction = function (i) {
if (animBool) {
    Fn.slideData(values(i)); // To fetch some data
    util.animate.tweenAnimate(sliderWrapper, 0 , Math.ceil("-"+sliderWidth));
    animBool = 0;
} else {
    util.animate.tweenAnimate(sliderWrapper, Math.ceil("-"+sliderWidth) ,0);
    animBool = 1;
}
}; 

for (i = 0; i < annotateArray.length; i++) {
//To Remember the state of value "i"
(function (i) {
    //Custom Event Listener for fallback for IE
    util.addEvent(annotateArray[i], "click", animateFunction(i), true);
}(i));
}

 for (i = 0; i < annotateArray.length; i++) {

    //Custom Remove Event Listener for fallback for IE
    util.removeEvent(annotateArray[i], "click", animateFunction);

}

//Custom Bind Event Method
util.addEvent = function (obj, evt, callback, capture) {
    if (window.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, callback);
    } else {
        if (!capture) {
            capture = false;
        }
        obj.addEventListener(evt, callback, capture);
    }
};
```

I am trying to bind event dynamically to all the elements but wen i click on the element the function doesn't behave as expected

Answer (score 1):

You're actually passing `undefined` as an event handler, not an actual callback. Here:

```
util.addEvent(annotateArray[i], "click", animateFunction(i), true);
```

You're invoking the function, which returns `undefined`. You must pass a function reference to `addEventListener`. You already have something "to Remember the state of value 'i'" in your loop, but you're not using it correctly. It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < annotateArray.length; i++) {
    //To Remember the state of value "i"
    (function (i) {
        // Custom Event Listener for fallback for IE
        util.addEvent(annotateArray[i], "click", function() {animateFunction(i)}, true);
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: hmmm, but I need to unbind that event too ... that the reason i passed the reference callback function... can u check the piece of edited code

Comment: Then you can create an array and store references to all handlers (like `function() {animateFunction(i)}`) there. You can use the references from the array later to unbind.

Comment: Thanks mate :) finally had to create an array and store references to all handlers